# XPath to verify every parent node has required child node

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to test if each specified parent node has one specified child node. For example, I have the following xml:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <cacheId/>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    // missing cacheId
  </entry>
</feed>
```

The second entry node doesn't have a child cacheId node. I need either an overall true/false if every entry parent node has one cacheId node; or a list of true/false for each entry node if it has the cacheId node.

So for the above xml, I need either false or the list (true, false).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With XPath 2.0 you can get a sequence of boolean values: `/feed/entry/boolean(cacheId)`. With XPath 1.0 you are restricted to `not(boolean(/feed/entry[not(cacheId)]))`.

Comment: Martin Honnen, legend of XPath, beats me to the punch. I humbly accept defeat.

Comment: @jdwilemo: What, no 1UP for your victor?

Comment: @MattH As if he actually needs my meager 1+, but sure.

Comment: @jdwilemo: well actually it's to recognise the completeness and correctness of the answer. Especially as it sounds like you had the same answer too :-) - Have a little recognition in your direction too.

Comment: Whoa, thanks MattH! And I agree, just thought the question was a little below @MartinHonnen haha, I've been trying to get his scraps lately.